# Setting a state in ReactJS gives me: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Can not setState property it is somehow undefined

Doing a `this.spin = this.spin.bind(this)` in constructor gives me a `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` and doing an arrow function  for spin gives me `Failed to compile`

```
import React  from 'react';
function getSeed() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() / 2)
}
var seed = getSeed();
function spin(timer) {
    var number = timer + [i] * 0.5;
    this.setState({number: number});
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        number:"",
      }
    };
      return (
      <div id="root"></div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: put the `spin()` into `App`

Comment: you are setting state out of the component. the function should be inside of the App component

Comment: Move the functions, where you are setting state, inside of class.

Comment: [answer-58215833](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215520/setting-a-state-in-reactjs-gives-me-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefine#answer-58215833) worked perfectly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: null,
    }
    this.getSeed = this.getSeed.bind(this);
    this.spin = this.spin.bind(this);
  };

  getSeed () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() / 2)
  }

  spin (timer, i) {
    var number = timer + [i] * 0.5;
    this.setState({
      number: number
    });
  }

  render() {
    var v_seed = this.getSeed();
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = { (e) => this.spin(12, 12)} > Click here </button>
        <div>{`${v_seed} ${this.state.number}`}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        number:"",
      }
    };
   getSeed() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() / 2)
   }
   let seed = getSeed();
   spin(timer) {
//[i] is not defined and it will fail so I am replacing it with  let number = timer * 0.5;
   let number = timer * 0.5;
   this.setState({number: number});
   }
   render(){
    return (
      <div id="root"></div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this if you when use react class

```
import React  from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        number:"",
      }
    };

    getSeed = () => {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() / 2)
    }

    spin(timer) = () => {
        this.setState({number: timer + [i] * 0.5});
    }
    render(){
        return (
           <div id="root"></div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

if you use react hook

```
import React, {useState}  from 'react';
const App = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
    const getSeed = () => {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() / 2)
    }

    const spin(timer) = () => {
        setNumber(timer + [i] * 0.5);
    }
    return (
       <div id="root"></div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code snippet, render was not there and moved the spin function inside class, I hope this will solve the issue.

```js
import React from "react";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: ""
    };
    this.spin = this.spin.bind(this);
  }

 spin(timer) {
     //logic
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="root"></div>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

also you can use arrow function as shown below, in this case you dont want to do the bind in constructor.

also if you are using latest version you dont want to use constructor, its already taken care by babel. you can read [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599) more about it

```
spin = () => {}
```